# assign elements in a list to different columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
l = [1,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
```

I'm trying to assign the elements of list `l` to the different columns in `df` but cannot find a way to do this. `df.append(l)` adds the list in one single column.

I would also like to be able to append other lists I create subsequently

```
l2 = [3,4]
df.append(l2)
```

This is the expected output

```
>>> df 
    x   y
    1   2
    3   4
    ... ...
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, they all work great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loc`

```
df.loc[len(df), :] = l
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `loc` with the `length of df`:

```
l = [1,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
df.loc[len(df)] = l

print(df,'\n')

l2 = [3,4]

df.loc[len(df)] = l2

print(df)
   x  y
0  1  2 

   x  y
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `Series` format your `list` then `append`

```
df=df.append(pd.Series(l,index=df.columns,name=0))
l2 = [3,4]
df=df.append(pd.Series(l2,index=df.columns,name=1))
df
Out[424]: 
   x  y
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You *could* use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to achieve exactly what you wanted:

```py
    columns = ['x','y']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

and then add "rows" like so:

```py
   l = [1,2]
   df = pd.concat((df, pd.DataFrame(data=[l], columns=columns)))
   l = [3,4]
   df = pd.concat((df, pd.DataFrame(data=[l], columns=columns)))
```

2. *However*, you could also do something like the following (if it makes sense in your real use case):

```py
   my_data = []
   my_data.append([1,2])
   my_data.append([3,4])
   # ...and then eventually:
   df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=list('xy'))
```